# How to ignore "possibly lost" in valgrind

Tags: valgrind, glib

I recently use valgrind with glib(with gobject), it doesn't work very well.

I have added `G_SLICE=always-malloc G_DEBUG=gc-friendly` in the command line,
but there's still many "possibly lost" reported by valgrind.

As I use valgrind in automated testsuit, so I add `--error-exitcode=1`,
but those "possibly lost" will make valgrind exit with 1, which will
case my test fail.

Does anyone know how to make valgrind not treat "possibly lost" as errors.

Answer (score 8):

With valgrind 3.7.0, use:
    --show-possibly-lost=no|yes      show possibly lost blocks in leak check?
                                     [yes]

Answer (score 0):

Check https://live.gnome.org/Valgrind for tips on how to use Valgrind with glib/gtk+/gnome.  You might be interested in the Suppressions's section.

Comment: I have read this before, it seems the suppression doesn't work very well. Maybe the glib's version is newer than the suppression.

Comment: The suppression file linked is for gtk+2, you can add the problematic functions there (for glib, at the end).  Do you have a small test case program and its corresponding output?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to make valgrind not treat "possibly lost" as errors.

Use `--errors-for-leak-kinds=definite` for this.  See [Valgrind User Manual,  Memcheck Command-Line Options section](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.options)